# Error installing flite on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, installation, makefile, static-libraries, flite

I have downloaded [the latest source distribution of flite](http://www.festvox.org/flite/download.html), and went about the usual process of installing it.

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

However, I run into a strange error when I try to install the library to my system.

```
$ sudo make install
Installing
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib
mkdir -p /usr/local/include/flite
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 include/*.h /usr/local/include/flite
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 ../bin/flite_time /usr/local/bin
cp -pd ../build/i386-darwin13.1.0/lib/libflite_cmu_us_kal.a ../build/i386-darwin13.1.0/lib/libflite_cmu_time_awb.a ../build/i386-darwin13.1.0/lib/libflite_cmu_us_kal16.a ../build/i386-darwin13.1.0/lib/libflite_cmu_us_awb.a ../build/i386-darwin13.1.0/lib/libflite_cmu_us_rms.a ../build/i386-darwin13.1.0/lib/libflite_cmu_us_slt.a ../build/i386-darwin13.1.0/lib/libflite_usenglish.a ../build/i386-darwin13.1.0/lib/libflite_cmulex.a ../build/i386-darwin13.1.0/lib/libflite.a /usr/local/lib
cp: illegal option -- d
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
make[1]: *** [install] Error 64
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There a few subtle differences between the BSD `cp` that Mac uses and the GNU `cp` of most linux distributions.

Consider the following snippet of `man cp` from a linux box:

```
   -d     same as --no-dereference --preserve=links

   -P, --no-dereference
          never follow symbolic links in SOURCE

   --preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
          preserve  the  specified  attributes (default: mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible additional attributes: context,
          links, xattr, all
```

So basically what it's trying to do is "copy the following paths, and if they're links, just copy the link, not the underlying file."

The `p` option exists under Mac and is equivalent to the linux behavior. The `d` option, however, is absent.

I've tried to figure out a way to mimic the behavior of "copy links, not targets" with the Mac `cp`, and as far as I can tell, there's no pleasant way to do it.

There is, fortunately, a gross work around. From `man cp` under Mac:

> Symbolic links are always followed unless the -R flag is set, in which case symbolic links are not followed, by default.

In other words, since we know we're only copying files, you can simply replace the `d` flag with the `R` flag. The behavior is technically different (*very* different), but it won't matter in this specific case. You'll need to find the `cp` flags used in the Makefile (hopefully in a `CP` variable at the top of the file) and simply change them.

If you're sure the `cp` is the last thing to be executed in the Makefile, you could also just copy and paste it instead of changing the Makefile.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem using Corbin's suggestion. After searching the Makefile, I was able to spot where the error originated.

I am using flite-2.0.0-release and the Makefile was located in the following directory:
`/flite-2.0.0-release/main/`.

The last couple lines has the following:

```
#       The libraries: static and shared (if built)
        cp -pd $(flite_LIBS_deps) $(INSTALLLIBDIR)
ifdef SHFLAGS
        cp -pd $(SHAREDLIBS) $(VERSIONSHAREDLIBS) $(INSTALLLIBDIR)
endif
```

I've changed the to the following:

```
#       The libraries: static and shared (if built)
        cp -pR $(flite_LIBS_deps) $(INSTALLLIBDIR)
ifdef SHFLAGS
        cp -pR $(SHAREDLIBS) $(VERSIONSHAREDLIBS) $(INSTALLLIBDIR)
endif
```

By replacing the `cp -pd` to `cp -pR`, I was able to successfully install flite. I hope this advice helps.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue recently, TJ Rana put me in the right direction but here's the whole process of installing flite on MacOS ([original article here](http://johnriselvato.com/how-to-install-flite-flitevox-for-ffmpeg/)):

---

Flitevox or Flitelib is an open source small run time speech engine. Pass it text and create an audio file with a robot saying it. Really cool and useful for some projects.

Flitelib is not a native filter available in FFmpeg build nor inside the source. Although the documentation states that –enable-libflite is required for config, installing flitelib is required before installing FFmpeg. If you do try to enable the filter you’ll get this error:

```
$ ./configure --disable-indevs --enable-libflite --enable-cross-compile
ERROR: libflite not found

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "ffbuild/config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.
```

In this post, I’ll show you how to install flite and get it working with FFmpeg

First download flitevox from source and install:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/festvox/flite.git
$ cd flite/
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

If you’re running linux this installation works perfectly. If you’re running MacOS, you’ll get this error:

```
$ sudo make install
Password:
Installing
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib
mkdir -p /usr/local/include/flite
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 include/*.h /usr/local/include/flite
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 ../bin/flite_time /usr/local/bin
cp -pd ../build/x86_64-darwin19.0.0/lib/libflite_cmu_us_kal.a ../build/x86_64-darwin19.0.0/lib/libflite_cmu_time_awb.a ../build/x86_64-darwin19.0.0/lib/libflite_cmu_us_kal16.a ../build/x86_64-darwin19.0.0/lib/libflite_cmu_us_awb.a ../build/x86_64-darwin19.0.0/lib/libflite_cmu_us_rms.a ../build/x86_64-darwin19.0.0/lib/libflite_cmu_us_slt.a ../build/x86_64-darwin19.0.0/lib/libflite_usenglish.a ../build/x86_64-darwin19.0.0/lib/libflite_cmu_indic_lang.a ../build/x86_64-darwin19.0.0/lib/libflite_cmu_grapheme_lang.a ../build/x86_64-darwin19.0.0/lib/libflite_cmulex.a ../build/x86_64-darwin19.0.0/lib/libflite_cmu_indic_lex.a ../build/x86_64-darwin19.0.0/lib/libflite_cmu_grapheme_lex.a ../build/x86_64-darwin19.0.0/lib/libflite.a /usr/local/lib
cp: illegal option -- d
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
make[1]: *** [install] Error 64
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

That’s because MacOS uses different “cp” variables then linux. I found this Stack Overflow answer with the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29075638/525576 but here’s the steps to fix it.

In the folder “flite/main” you’ll need to edit the Makefile with the MacOS version of the command:

```
$ cd main/
$ vim Makefile
```

Replace the following (from TJ Rana):

```
#       The libraries: static and shared (if built)
        cp -pd $(flite_LIBS_deps) $(INSTALLLIBDIR)
ifdef SHFLAGS
        cp -pd $(SHAREDLIBS) $(VERSIONSHAREDLIBS) $(INSTALLLIBDIR)
endif
```

to (-pd to -pR):

```
#       The libraries: static and shared (if built)
        cp -pR $(flite_LIBS_deps) $(INSTALLLIBDIR)
ifdef SHFLAGS
        cp -pR $(SHAREDLIBS) $(VERSIONSHAREDLIBS) $(INSTALLLIBDIR)
endif
```

How we can try installing flite again:

```
$ sudo make install
```

flite should not show any errors and the installation should be complete.

Now back in ffmpeg source filter:

```
$ ./configure --enable-libflite --enable-cross-compile
$ make install
```

Installation will complete. To test if flite is working open a new terminal and type:

```
$ ffplay -f lavfi -i flite=text='Hello World!'
```

Hello world will speak!