# How to install flite for epitran on Windows

Tags: c++, makefile, flite

I'm trying to use python's package epitran https://pypi.org/project/epitran/0.10/ on windows which returns the IPA representation of words. For english, as the website says, I need to install flite from here http://tts.speech.cs.cmu.edu/awb/flite-2.0.5-current.tar.bz2.

After some research on the web I have gotten to download the file and trying installing it using cygwin.

I also changed both instances of cp -pd to cp -pR as epitran's website and this [Error installing flite on Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001775/error-installing-flite-on-mac-osx) suggested.

So far I've  executed the following lines in my cygwin terminal.

```
$ tar xjf flite-2.0.5-current.tar.bz2

$ cd flite-2.0.5-current
```

But when I execute this:

```
$ ./configure && make
```

I get the following error

```
gcc   -I. -DCST_AUDIO_NONE -I../../include -g -O2 -Wall     -c auclient.c -o ../../build/x86_64-cygwin/obj/src/audio/auclient.o
In file included from auclient.c:46:0:
../../include/cst_file.h: In function 'c99_vsnprintf':
../../include/cst_file.h:108:20: warning: implicit declaration of function '_vsnprintf_s' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
            count = _vsnprintf_s(str, size, _TRUNCATE, format, ap);
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../../include/cst_file.h:108:44: error: '_TRUNCATE' undeclared (first use in this function)
            count = _vsnprintf_s(str, size, _TRUNCATE, format, ap);
                                            ^~~~~~~~~
../../include/cst_file.h:108:44: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[2]: *** [../../config/common_make_rules:105: ../../build/x86_64-cygwin/obj/src/audio/auclient.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [../config/common_make_rules:133: ../build/x86_64-cygwin/obj/src/.make_build_dirs] Error 2
make: *** [config/common_make_rules:133: build/x86_64-cygwin/obj//.make_build_dirs] Error 2
```

I basically have no idea what I'm doing and what the error might be since I have 0 experience with C++ or Linux so I'd be really grateful if someone gave me some help